# How to move uberSVN to another server?

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I'm using uberSVN on Ubuntu server for my project development. Now I need to move uberSVN to another server (backup all data of uberSVN and SVN data).

How to move uberSVN to another server ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup your repositories. See [Repository Backup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup) at SVNBook,
2. Install UberSVN on the other machine,
3. Move your repositories backup to the new machine.

It's actually all you need to move your repos however the steps depend on your particular case. You may need to deal with SSL certificates, relocating WCs if the server's URL changes, etc etc.

Comment: Backing up the uberSVN data is needed too, how to do this is detailed here: http://docs.ubersvn.com/v1.0/reference.html#R79